# Check if is on child-page of a particular page

Tags: pages, child-pages

I am trying to output a logo depending on which page is being viewed.

```
<?php if ( is_page('home') || is_page('services') ) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
        <?php ci_e_logo('<h1 class="logo ' . get_logo_class() . '">', '</h1>'); ?>
    </div>
<?php } 
else { ?>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
        <h1 class="logo imglogo">
            <a href="http://websiteaddress.com">
                <img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/picturehere.png" alt="title here"></a>
            </h1>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

The code above works fine, but how do apply the logo image swap on the sub-pages of the 'services'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php 
global $post;

if ( is_page('home') || is_page('services') ) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
        <?php ci_e_logo('<h1 class="logo ' . get_logo_class() . '">', '</h1>'); ?>
    </div>
<?php } 

elseif ( preg_match( '#^service(/.+)?$#', $wp->request ) ) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
        <?php ci_e_logo('<h1 class="logo ' . get_logo_class() . '">', '</h1>'); ?>
    </div>
<?php
}

else { ?>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
        <h1 class="logo imglogo">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/picturehere.png" alt=""></a>
            </h1>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 15):

You can do that with `$post->post_parent`. You will have to check if child page's parent is Services page. So this is how you will check it.

I assumed `123` in following code is page ID of your services page. Replace it with actual ID.

```
if ( 123 == $post->post_parent ) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
        <?php ci_e_logo('<h1 class="logo ' . get_logo_class() . '">', '</h1>'); ?>
    </div>
<?php }
```

Comment: Just a note that this won't work for descendants (ie, two sub-pages down), though it's still a better answer than the one selected IMO.

Answer (score 8):

You can get the Post page / post name using this method.

```
$parent = array_reverse(get_post_ancestors($post->ID));
$page_parent = get_post($parent[0]);
echo $page_parent->post_name;
```

you can use the condition as per your requirements.

Comment: Please format your code properly before posting.

Answer (score 4):

Same as Robert Hue's answer, this solution will get you the ID of the parent element:

```
echo get_post_field( 'post_parent' );
```

The second parameter is optional and can hold an ID (for when you are outside the loop or want to query the parent of a specific element)

```
$post_ID = 666;
echo get_post_field( 'post_parent', $post_ID );
```

This function can get you any field from the post table, like the post slug, status, type... see the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_field/) for all available fields.

In your case the function would look like this:

```
if ( get_post_field( 'post_parent' ) === 9 ) :
    //child of page ID 9
endif;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```php
if ( wp_get_post_parent_id( get_the_ID() ) != 0 ) {
    echo 'I am a child page';
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `get_post_ancestors($post)`. It will return an array if the current shown post is child of your parent page.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Could you please clarify how I would implement this using or modifying the code I currently have?

Comment: I don't think this will solve the problem since this functions `get_post_ancestors()` only returns array of child page. It's good for checking if a page has child pages.

Answer (score 0):

```
$post_current = get_post();

$args = array(
        'post_parent' => $parent_id, // the ID of the parent
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'page',

);
$children = get_posts($args);

$is_child = false;

foreach ($children as $f) {
    if ( $f->ID == $post_current->post_parent ) {
        // it's a child 
        $is_child = true;
        break;
    }
}

if ($is_child) {
    // I'ts a child...
} else {
    // It is not a child...
}
```

Comment: Recommend you provide some additional information with your answer.  Some reference and context would be helpful to the next reader.  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer