# if is_page('slug')

Tags: conditional-tags

Say I have a page domain.com/jibbly_bits and domain.com/jibbly_bits/small

I'm trying to make a conditional statement where if it is a certain page or that page with a subpage after it. I've tried using just the parent slug, the parent slug with a "/" after it and also tried a wild card after it like so "/*"

The following attempts were unsuccessful.... any ideas ?

```
<?php if (is_page('jibbly_bits')) : ?>

<?php if (is_page('jibbly_bits/')) : ?>

<?php if (is_page('jibbly_bits/*')) : ?>
```

Comment: and I need it to work dynamically without hardcoding the subpage slug

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if is on child-page of a particular page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/169306/check-if-is-on-child-page-of-a-particular-page)

Comment: Nope that wasn't me but I'll check it out

Answer (score 1):

Solved, this is what I was looking for:

```
<?php elseif (preg_match( '#^any-page-with-this-text-in-slug(/.+)?$#', $wp->request)) : ?>
```